# Scalar line integral, surface integral, change of variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

When we do a scalar line integral, we parameterize the curve, then integrate, but we introduce the magnitude of the derivative of our parameterization into the integral.
When we do a surface integral, we integrate over the domain of the parameterization of the surface and introduce the Jacobian.
When we do a change of variables, we also introduce the Jacobian.

Are these all similar in that we integrate over a new domain and now have to "adjust" to make the integral correct? Is the some sort of Jacobian used in the scalar line integral? Is this all because we are now integrating over a new domain?